# Glitch initialising matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix in C in order to solve the LaPlacian

However, this is going wrong. I have located the problem at the initialisation stage of the matrix. Every time the program is run, it places a seemingly random value in one element. This number changes each time suggesting an instability in the code, and happens if the matrix is made to be greater than 9x9.

Why could this be happening?

Thanks

The code I am using to show the matrix is:

```
  // create matrix 
  double mat[meshno][meshno] = { {0} };  // x direction defined by i, y by j

  //variables 
  int i, j, k;

  //print initial matrix
for (i=0;i<=meshno;i++)
 { 
for(j=0;j<= meshno;j++)
 {
   printf("%f ", mat[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at an element past the end of each array.

Your for loops should use `<` and not `<=`:

```
for (i = 0; i < meshno; ++i)
{ 
 for(j = 0; j < meshno; ++j)
 {
```

Comment: @user2137944 rather than leaving a comment use StackExchange's tool for saying thanks and accept the answer

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227203). See _[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227203)_ to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
for (i=0; i< meshno;i++)
 { 
for(j=0; j< meshno;j++)
 {
```